# Is it possible to get more than one mystery box in one run?

Tags: subway-surfers

Every time I play, I can't get more than one mystery box in one run (top score 1.5m).

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get multiple mystery boxes during run.

Chances are:

1. One simple mystery box
2. Super mystery boxes after completing challanges (1 per 3 challanges)
3. Super mystery boxes during super mystery event.

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) +1 and accept from me. I already [mentioned](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/199685/80468) that I can get more than one mystery box in my other answer, but I didn't know that it happens that way :)

Answer (score 0):

From [Subway Surfers wiki](http://subwaysurf.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Box):

> You can get multiple mystery boxes per run, most likely 2 or 3.

So I just haven't been playing enough :D